Early Stopping does not have metrics on Colab
I was trying to have a go on NeRFstudio and followed this tutorial here and also ([github link of this tutorial])(https://github.com/kwea123/nerf_pl), with some tweaks to the train.py and requirements.txt because these files are outdated. But despite many tries, I am still unable to train successfully.
My requirements.txt:
torch
torchvision
pytorch-lightning==1.6.0
test-tube
kornia
opencv-python
matplotlib
jupyter

# for mesh
PyMCubes
pycollada
trimesh
pyglet

# for point cloud
plyfile
open3d

My train.py:
import os
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from opt import get_opts
import torch
from collections import defaultdict

from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from datasets import dataset_dict

# models
from models.nerf import Embedding, NeRF
from models.rendering import render_rays

# optimizer, scheduler, visualization
from utils import *

# losses
from losses import loss_dict

# metrics
from metrics import *

# pytorch-lightning
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from pytorch_lightning import LightningModule, Trainer
from pytorch_lightning.loggers import TestTubeLogger
from pytorch_lightning.profiler import PyTorchProfiler

class NeRFSystem(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, hparams):
        super(NeRFSystem, self).__init__()
        self.save_hyperparameters(hparams)
        # self.hparams = hparams

        self.loss = loss_dict[hparams.loss_type]()

        self.embedding_xyz = Embedding(3, 10) # 10 is the default number
        self.embedding_dir = Embedding(3, 4) # 4 is the default number
        self.embeddings = [self.embedding_xyz, self.embedding_dir]

        self.nerf_coarse = NeRF()
        self.models = [self.nerf_coarse]
        if hparams.N_importance > 0:
            self.nerf_fine = NeRF()
            self.models += [self.nerf_fine]

    def decode_batch(self, batch):
        rays = batch['rays'] # (B, 8)
        rgbs = batch['rgbs'] # (B, 3)
        return rays, rgbs

    def forward(self, rays):
        """Do batched inference on rays using chunk."""
        B = rays.shape[0]
        results = defaultdict(list)
        for i in range(0, B, self.hparams.chunk):
            rendered_ray_chunks = \
                render_rays(self.models,
                            self.embeddings,
                            rays[i:i+self.hparams.chunk],
                            self.hparams.N_samples,
                            self.hparams.use_disp,
                            self.hparams.perturb,
                            self.hparams.noise_std,
                            self.hparams.N_importance,
                            self.hparams.chunk, # chunk size is effective in val mode
                            self.train_dataset.white_back)

            for k, v in rendered_ray_chunks.items():
                results[k] += [v]

        for k, v in results.items():
            results[k] = torch.cat(v, 0)
        return results

    def prepare_data(self):
        dataset = dataset_dict[self.hparams.dataset_name]
        kwargs = {'root_dir': self.hparams.root_dir,
                  'img_wh': tuple(self.hparams.img_wh)}
        if self.hparams.dataset_name == 'llff':
            kwargs['spheric_poses'] = self.hparams.spheric_poses
            kwargs['val_num'] = self.hparams.num_gpus
        self.train_dataset = dataset(split='train', **kwargs)
        self.val_dataset = dataset(split='val', **kwargs)

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        self.optimizer = get_optimizer(self.hparams, self.models)
        scheduler = get_scheduler(self.hparams, self.optimizer)
        
        return [self.optimizer], [scheduler]

    def train_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.train_dataset,
                          shuffle=True,
                          num_workers=4,
                          batch_size=self.hparams.batch_size,
                          pin_memory=True)

    def val_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.val_dataset,
                          shuffle=False,
                          num_workers=4,
                          batch_size=1, # validate one image (H*W rays) at a time
                          pin_memory=True)
    
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_nb):
        log = {'lr': get_learning_rate(self.optimizer)}
        rays, rgbs = self.decode_batch(batch)
        results = self(rays)
        log['train/loss'] = loss = self.loss(results, rgbs)
        typ = 'fine' if 'rgb_fine' in results else 'coarse'

        with torch.no_grad():
            psnr_ = psnr(results[f'rgb_{typ}'], rgbs)
            log['train/psnr'] = psnr_

        return {'loss': loss,
                'progress_bar': {'train_psnr': psnr_},
                'log': log
               }

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_nb):
        rays, rgbs = self.decode_batch(batch)
        rays = rays.squeeze() # (H*W, 3)
        rgbs = rgbs.squeeze() # (H*W, 3)
        results = self(rays)
        log = {'val_loss': self.loss(results, rgbs)}
        typ = 'fine' if 'rgb_fine' in results else 'coarse'
    
        if batch_nb == 0:
            W, H = self.hparams.img_wh
            img = results[f'rgb_{typ}'].view(H, W, 3).cpu()
            img = img.permute(2, 0, 1) # (3, H, W)
            img_gt = rgbs.view(H, W, 3).permute(2, 0, 1).cpu() # (3, H, W)
            depth = visualize_depth(results[f'depth_{typ}'].view(H, W)) # (3, H, W)
            stack = torch.stack([img_gt, img, depth]) # (3, 3, H, W)
            self.logger.experiment.add_images('val/GT_pred_depth',
                                               stack, self.global_step)

        log['val_psnr'] = psnr(results[f'rgb_{typ}'], rgbs)
        return log

    def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs):
        mean_loss = torch.stack([x['val_loss'] for x in outputs]).mean()
        mean_psnr = torch.stack([x['val_psnr'] for x in outputs]).mean()

        return {'progress_bar': {'val_loss': mean_loss,
                                 'val_psnr': mean_psnr},
                'log': {'val/loss': mean_loss,
                        'val/psnr': mean_psnr}
               }
    def lr_scheduler_step(self, scheduler, optimizer_idx, monitor_val=None):
        scheduler.step()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    hparams = get_opts()
    system = NeRFSystem(hparams)
    
    checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(dirpath=os.path.join(f'ckpts/{hparams.exp_name}',
                                                                '{epoch:d}'),
                                          monitor='val/loss',
                                          mode='min',
                                          save_top_k=5,)

    logger = TestTubeLogger(
        save_dir="logs",
        name=hparams.exp_name,
        debug=False,
        create_git_tag=False
    )
    early_stop_callback = EarlyStopping(
        monitor=None,
        min_delta=0.0,
        patience=3,
        verbose=True,
        mode='min'
    )


    trainer = Trainer(max_epochs=hparams.num_epochs, 
              callbacks=[early_stop_callback],
              checkpoint_callback=checkpoint_callback,
              resume_from_checkpoint=hparams.ckpt_path,
              logger=logger,
              weights_summary=None,
              progress_bar_refresh_rate=1,
              gpus=hparams.num_gpus,
              # distributed_backend='ddp' if hparams.num_gpus>1 else None,
              strategy='ddp' if hparams.num_gpus>1 else None,
              num_sanity_val_steps=1,
              benchmark=True,
              profiler=PyTorchProfiler()
              # profiler=hparams.num_gpus==1
              )
              
    trainer.fit(system)

Error mesage in output:
/content/nerf_pl
2024-06-03 18:46:09.172368: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9261] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2024-06-03 18:46:09.172420: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:607] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2024-06-03 18:46:09.173586: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1515] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2024-06-03 18:46:10.244937: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/loggers/test_tube.py:105: LightningDeprecationWarning: The TestTubeLogger is deprecated since v1.5 and will be removed in v1.7. We recommend switching to the `pytorch_lightning.loggers.TensorBoardLogger` as an alternative.
  rank_zero_deprecation(
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/connectors/callback_connector.py:151: LightningDeprecationWarning: Setting `Trainer(checkpoint_callback=<pytorch_lightning.callbacks.model_checkpoint.ModelCheckpoint object at 0x7c8e0b5d9990>)` is deprecated in v1.5 and will be removed in v1.7. Please consider using `Trainer(enable_checkpointing=<pytorch_lightning.callbacks.model_checkpoint.ModelCheckpoint object at 0x7c8e0b5d9990>)`.
  rank_zero_deprecation(
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/connectors/callback_connector.py:96: LightningDeprecationWarning: Setting `Trainer(progress_bar_refresh_rate=1)` is deprecated in v1.5 and will be removed in v1.7. Please pass `pytorch_lightning.callbacks.progress.TQDMProgressBar` with `refresh_rate` directly to the Trainer's `callbacks` argument instead. Or, to disable the progress bar pass `enable_progress_bar = False` to the Trainer.
  rank_zero_deprecation(
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/connectors/callback_connector.py:171: LightningDeprecationWarning: Setting `Trainer(weights_summary=None)` is deprecated in v1.5 and will be removed in v1.7. Please set `Trainer(enable_model_summary=False)` instead.
  rank_zero_deprecation(
GPU available: True, used: True
TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores
IPU available: False, using: 0 IPUs
HPU available: False, using: 0 HPUs
val image is /content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/nerf/nerf_llff_data/fern/images/IMG_4038.JPG
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/callbacks/model_checkpoint.py:608: UserWarning: Checkpoint directory logs/fern/version_None/checkpoints exists and is not empty.
  rank_zero_warn(f"Checkpoint directory {dirpath} exists and is not empty.")
LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0]
Sanity Checking: 0it [00:00, ?it/s]/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py:66: RuntimeWarning: os.fork() was called. os.fork() is incompatible with multithreaded code, and JAX is multithreaded, so this will likely lead to a deadlock.
  self.pid = os.fork()
Sanity Checking DataLoader 0:   0% 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/profiler/pytorch.py:419: UserWarning: The PyTorch Profiler default schedule will be overridden as there is not enough steps to properly record traces.
  warning_cache.warn(
STAGE:2024-06-03 18:46:32 28448:28448 ActivityProfilerController.cpp:314] Completed Stage: Warm Up
Epoch 0: 100% 3535/3536 [07:41<00:00,  7.67it/s, loss=0.0146, v_num=0]
Validation: 0it [00:00, ?it/s]/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py:66: RuntimeWarning: os.fork() was called. os.fork() is incompatible with multithreaded code, and JAX is multithreaded, so this will likely lead to a deadlock.
  self.pid = os.fork()

Validation DataLoader 0:   0% 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Epoch 0: 100% 3536/3536 [07:51<00:00,  7.49it/s, loss=0.0146, v_num=0]
                                                          Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/nerf_pl/train.py", line 199, in <module>
    trainer.fit(system)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 771, in fit
    self._call_and_handle_interrupt(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 724, in _call_and_handle_interrupt
    return trainer_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 812, in _fit_impl
    results = self._run(model, ckpt_path=self.ckpt_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 1237, in _run
    results = self._run_stage()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 1324, in _run_stage
    return self._run_train()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 1354, in _run_train
    self.fit_loop.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/base.py", line 205, in run
    self.on_advance_end()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/fit_loop.py", line 297, in on_advance_end
    self.trainer._call_callback_hooks("on_train_epoch_end")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 1637, in _call_callback_hooks
    fn(self, self.lightning_module, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/callbacks/early_stopping.py", line 179, in on_train_epoch_end
    self._run_early_stopping_check(trainer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/callbacks/early_stopping.py", line 190, in _run_early_stopping_check
    if trainer.fast_dev_run or not self._validate_condition_metric(  # disable early_stopping with fast_dev_run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/callbacks/early_stopping.py", line 145, in _validate_condition_metric
    raise RuntimeError(error_msg)
RuntimeError: Early stopping conditioned on metric `None` which is not available. Pass in or modify your `EarlyStopping` callback to use any of the following: ``
[W observer.cpp:104] Warning: Leaked callback handle: 1 (function operator())

Not allowing "NONE" as a metric for Early Stopping is a problem, but also from what I've googled I saw everyone had "val_loss" at least as a metric choice, but mine had no metrics at all.Tried "tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()" but to no avail as well.
